# Flow for scheduling payments

Tags: usability, payment, user-journey

So am working on a mobile app that allows users to send money & pay their bills (electricity & telephone)

Am adding a feature where these payments can be scheduled in advance.
However i am confused on how the flow will work.
I want to keep it as simple as possible so that the user has no difficulty in understanding how to schedule the payments.

Currently am thinking that the user will select the type of payment, then I will ask him to select a future date for the payment. After he is done with that I will ask whether he would like to repeat this schedule....if he says yes then he can select weekly, monthly or yearly option which means I will automatically select the future dates for the week or month or year.I think this flow can be made a lot simpler.I would love to hear how you guys would prefer to do it.

Also another problem is that utility payments like electricity bills & telephone bills are only paid once a month but the other payments types such as sending money can be scheduled in pretty much any way a user might want.How can i make a flow that allows the users to make the maximum type of schedules ?Your help will be really appreciated.Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can use patterns similar to alarms and custom reminder setting that you can find in android or ios devices. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your entire screen flow of UX design which you have done,  but as far as my understanding based on your question I can tell you simply as below.

When user selecting utility payments such as electricity & telephone bills, we can display payment schedule option in order to future date payment setup.  Otherwise if user wants to sending money to anybody or any accounts, we can show data picker (for later payment schedule) or now option to initiate money transfer... Hope it helps...